# Why does rapid api return no json?

Tags: java, json

I am a beginner in webscraping and I am currently developing an app using rapid api platform to fetch some jsons. Once you are looking for a specific endpoint, you are provided a code snipped you should paste in your program. Thus I runned this code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class AAA {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/fixtures/league/1383/last/10?timezone=Europe%252FLondon")
                .get()
                .addHeader("x-rapidapi-host", "api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com")
                .addHeader("x-rapidapi-key", "myRapidAPIKey")
                .build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        System.out.println(response.toString());
    }
}
```

But the same **NOT JSON** output is displayed over and over again, no matter what endpoint I am selecting:

```
Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/predictions/157462}
```

I am not using maven. I have just included the necessary jars for my code to work. What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance?

Answer (score 0):

The json typically is contained in the response body. So you have to try something like:

```
System.out.println(response.body().string());
```

Instead of

```
System.out.println(response.toString());
```